# How to simultaneously collect all captured substrings using re.match() ?

Tags: python, regex

I'm applying a number of regex patterns to text entries, and I wish for them to be automatically entered into a list.

e.g.

```
import re
raw='NIH05484225_1_binders_list ID_054345 Proteincomplex /D1/ERBH1_ERV_ACWX'

regex= '.*Proteincomplex /[\S]+\/([\S]+)_([\S]+)_([\S]+)'
regex=re.compile(regex)


result = re.match(regex, raw)
answer=[]
answer.append (result.group(1))
answer.append (result.group(2))
answer.append (result.group(3))

print (answer)
```

Is there a way to have `answer` collect all the captured results?
As in

`answer.extend (result.allgroups()) # does not work, of course`

Comment: Did you try `result.groups()`?

Comment: That's exactly what I needed!

Comment: Please check [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects) first next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [`Match.groups()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.groups):

> Return a tuple containing all the subgroups of the match, from 1 up to however many groups are in the pattern. The *default* argument is used for groups that did not participate in the match; it defaults to `None`.

So, you may modify the code this way:

```
import re
raw='NIH05484225_1_binders_list ID_054345 Proteincomplex /D1/ERBH1_ERV_ACWX'
regex=re.compile(r'.*Proteincomplex\s+/\S+\/(\S+)_(\S+)_(\S+)')
result = re.match(regex, raw)
if result:
    print (answer.groups())
```

Note you do not need to wrap each single `\S` with a character class and a `\s+` instead of a space will let you match any one or more whitespace (it is considered more readable and fail-safe, especially if you plan to use `re.VERBOSE` / `re.X` later to insert comments or formatting whitespace into the pattern).